# API and main page as two separated processes

Tags: nginx, performance, django, gunicorn

### SITUATION

I created an REST API for my mobile application and now I want to create a website. API so far is very very simple, just for a couple requests like 'get list of contents', 'update some field in database' etc. But now, I want to create a website which will use the same database of course.
I don't think that this API will be useful in the website project.

### QUESTION

It is better to keep API and website separatelly, on two different gunicorn instances, or it is better to merge it? For example API on `api.example.com` with address `127.0.0.1:8001` and website on `example.com` with address `127.0.0.1:8002` and of course on two different nginx server configurations (2 files in sites-available/enabled if you still doesn't know what I mean :P)? Or doesn't matter on performance with handling requests and it's better to do one project with link `example.com/api/...`?

Comment: Your api doesn't sound like REST to me - by your description its RPC - JSON does not a REST API make. As for the question it depends but i'd say in most cases separate is better.

Comment: If you had done a RESTful API I suspect you'd be using it in the new web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For production, I'd recommend to keep the applications separate as you suggest (in two different nginx sites).

Divide your Django project in applications: ie. 'core', 'api', 'web'. This way, you can share the application containing the models and logic 'core', and have the two other applications 'api' and 'web' reuse that code.

Because in fact you are describing two services (API and web), you can easily create two different settings.py and wsgi for Django, each of them including the appropriate applications. This is a common approach: each application includes and exposes only the code that it needs. Having separate domain names and services would allow for an easier and better distribution as the site grows. Also, it allows for easier fine-tuning of each application configuration (logging settings, middleware, etc).

If your application doesn't need to support so many requests, I'd be happy keeping a single settings.py and simply using URLs to direct requests to one application or another. You can do this for development too.

If you wish to include one or other URLs depending settings, use something like:

```
# Your generic URL patterns
urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    #(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve'),
    ...
)

if settings.ENABLE_API:
    urlpatterns += patterns('', 
        url(r'^', include('myapi.urls')),
    ) 

if settings.ENABLE_WEB:    
    urlpatterns += patterns('', 
        url(r'^', include('web.urls')),
        #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

The above is just an example, the point is that you can build your URL patterns conditionally or for example use the + operator to add more patterns to them. More info at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/ .

Comment: So, you suggest to create for example an `api-settings.py` with `api.wsgi` and `web-settings.py` with `web.wsgi`, where in api-settings api application will be included but web will not? But what to do with urls? Also define it in `api-settings` and `web-settings` to `urls.py` in each application? And I'm using Django 1.7 with Python 3.4

Comment: Yes, you can do that. For URLs, you can also point your settings.py to different urls.py, which then include the appropriate urls.py from subapplications (remember you can and should have a urls.py on each application, including with ie. `url(r'^api/1.0/', include('myapi.urls', namespace='myapi'))`). For organisation, I usually keep api URLS within  "/api/" which doesn't conflict with website or other apps, even if they are deployed in the same process. I hope to have made sense here...

Comment: Yes, I'm keeping my urls in each app. I asked about that option in settings.py because if I will not include web application in api-settings.py then include in main urls.py can cause error. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. Also note you can also include one or other URLs conditionally, depending on the availability of the module or depending on some setting, or simply have separate main urls.py. It's more of a matter of taste or final application (ie. if you need people to enable or disable functionality from config -> then use a custom setting and conditional logic in your main urls.py).

Comment: how to add URLs conditionally to urls.py? I've never heard about this feature :P

Comment: Added to the response. This thread is now getting too long. Rather, ask new questions ;-). Hope it helps.